# Parsing JSON with SQL: How to extract a record within a JSON object?

Tags: sql-server, json, string, t-sql

I'm looking at about 13,000 rows in a SQL Server table, and trying to parse out certain values within one column that is stored as json.

The json column values look something like this:

```
..."http://www.companyurl.com","FoundedYear":"2007","Status":"Private","CompanySize":"51-200","TagLine":"We build software we believe in","Origi...
```

I'd like to extract the value for "CompanySize", but not all rows include this attribute. Other complicating factors:

- I'm not sure how many possible values there are within the "CompanySize" parameter.
- "CompanySize" is not always followed by the "TagLine" parameter.

The one rule I know for certain: the CompanySize value is always a string of unknown length that follows the varchar string `"CompanySize":"` and terminates before the next `","` string.

Ideally we would have upgraded fully to SQL Server 2016 so I'd be able to take advantage of [SQL Server's JSON support](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jocapc/archive/2015/05/16/json-support-in-sql-server-2016.aspx), but that's not the case.

Comment: https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/consuming-json-strings-in-sql-server/

Comment: Since there's no possibility of indexing such data, nor is there any way to return results without fully scanning your table, unless the relevant string is really huge that you'd like to avoid doing so - I'd just return the entire string and have it processed within a proper environment.

Comment: What @Amit said, and even better: actually create a table or schema for this data, and store it properly in the first place.

Comment: @Amit Why are you assuming that this value is being filtered on? Indexing might not be relevant anyway. It's also fairly easy to get this value and 13k rows is hardly any data to begin with.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn You are making some assumptions here that might not be fair. It could be that they already process this data in the app layer, but now there is one particular reason to need a value in the DB that wasn't thought about originally, and no need to store the data twice. I have worked on a system where data was throw in as JSON because the developers liked it and there was no concern about needing to parse it later in the DB. In that case XML makes more sense since it can be parsed in both places.

Comment: @srutzky - I'm not assuming that. The contrary... I'm saying that it's impossible to filter. And if that's the case, then there's no good reason not to return the entire string and parse it with a more suitable tool set.

Comment: @Amit Why does filtering matter? What if the client isn't the app layer? What if it is needed in a SQL Agent job (for whatever reason), or a report? This could be merely a value to grab on rows that have already been filtered. If the client is the app layer, then I probably would agree that the field should be returned as is and parsed there. But there are definitely scenarios when that is not the case.

Comment: @srutzky - I see your case, and it does make sense but that would mean the data is stored incorrectly in the first place. Would you accept a date stored as a blob "because the developers liked it"? And then would you go through hoops to do simple queries because of that?

Comment: @Amit Is the data stored incorrectly? Yup. Would I accept such a situation if I had any say in the matter? Hell no. Do I always have a say in the matter? Absolutely not! And that's the issue. I have come into projects that already had fairly large (and sometimes horribly wrong) data models. I do what I can to fix those situations, but often times, even if I am spot on and everyone agrees with the proposed changes, it requires app code changes as well and QA time, and the business sometimes has other priorities and I am not allowed to do the fix. This situation is more common than it should be.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with `CHARINDEX` since you can pass it a start position, which will allow you to get the closing `"`. You probably shouldn't look for `","` since if `CompanySize` is the final property, it won't have the `,"` at the end of that fragment. Doing this as an Inline Table-Valued Function (iTVF) will be pretty efficient (especially since 13k rows is almost nothing), you just need to use it with either `CROSS APPLY` or `OUTER APPLY`:

```sql
USE [tempdb];
GO

CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetCompanySize(@JSON NVARCHAR(MAX))
RETURNS TABLE
AS RETURN

WITH SearchStart AS
(
  SELECT '"CompanySize":"' AS [Fragment]
), Search AS
(
  SELECT CHARINDEX(ss.Fragment, @JSON) AS [Start],
         LEN(ss.Fragment) AS [FragmentLength]
  FROM   SearchStart ss
)
SELECT CASE Search.Start
         WHEN 0 THEN NULL
         ELSE SUBSTRING(@JSON,
                        (Search.Start + Search.FragmentLength),
                        CHARINDEX('"',
                                  @JSON,
                                  Search.Start + Search.FragmentLength
                                 ) - (Search.Start + Search.FragmentLength)
                       )
       END AS [CompanySize]
FROM Search;
GO
```

Set up the test:

```sql
CREATE TABLE #tmp (JSON NVARCHAR(MAX));

INSERT INTO #tmp (JSON) VALUES
('"http://www.companyurl.com","FoundedYear":"2007","Status":"Private","CompanySize":"51-200","TagLine":"We build software we believe in","Origi..');
INSERT INTO #tmp (JSON) VALUES
('"http://www.companyurl.com","FoundedYear":"2009","Status":"Public","TagLine":"We build software we believe in","Origi..');
INSERT INTO #tmp (JSON) VALUES (NULL);
```

Run the test:

```sql
SELECT comp.CompanySize
FROM   #tmp tmp
CROSS APPLY tempdb.dbo.GetCompanySize(tmp.JSON) comp
```

Returns:

```
CompanySize
-----------
51-200
NULL
NULL
```

Comment: Thanks @srutzky this was helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Building on @srutzky 's answer, the following solution avoids creating a UDF (although you didn't say that was a constraint, it might be useful for some).

```
select
    c.Id,
    substring(i2.jsontail, 0, i3.[length]) CompanySize
from
    Companies c cross apply
    ( select charindex('CompanySize":"', c.json) start ) i1 cross apply
    ( select substring(c.json, start + len('CompanySize":"'), len(c.json) - start ) jsontail ) i2 cross apply
    ( select charindex('"', i2.jsontail) [length] ) i3
where
    i1.[start] != 0
```